# JPA querydsl join other database?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, testing, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

i have two data base connection in project

Ex.

1. test1
2. test2

test1 database has user table and test2 database has classmember

I was already settings multiple databases in jpa configuration.

There are created each database table.

Jpa querydsl possible multiple databases join?

Mybatis is possible. because mybatis can write native query in project xml files.

Anyway it possible?

Answer (score 0):

@Table(name = "table naem", catalog ="other schema")